# In Next Js, Why api gets triggered multiple times instead of one even though the strictmode is set to false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

**Next Js**

As you can see in this code, I am trying to hit an API when the value of selectedAmc changes. But every time the value of selectedAmc changes, the API gets triggered four times instead of just once. I also tried changing the strict mode to false in the next.config.js file but it didn't work. What is the solution for this? I've faced similar problems in many other cases as well where the API hits more than once.

```
import { Select } from "antd";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { postSchemeName } from "../../../pages/mis-reports/mis-api";

const { Option } = Select;

type Props = {
  className?: string;
  selectedAmc?: string;
};

const SchemeName = ({ className, selectedAmc }: Props) => {
  const { data: schemeData, refetch: fetchSchemeName } = useQuery<any, any>(
    ["post-scheme", { fund_house_name: selectedAmc }],
    postSchemeName,
    {
      enabled: false,
    }
  );

  const onChange = (value: string) => {};

  const onSearch = (value: string) => {};

  console.log("selected amc--->", selectedAmc);

  //API gets triggered four times when the selectedAmc value changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    typeof selectedAmc === "undefined" ? null : fetchSchemeName();
  }, [selectedAmc, fetchSchemeName]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mb-4 xxs:w-[100%] xs:w-[45%] sm:w-[30%]">
        <p className="mb-1">Scheme Name</p>
        <Select
          className={`h-10 ${className} w-full`}
          showSearch
          size="large"
          placeholder="Scheme Name..."
          optionFilterProp="children"
          onChange={onChange}
          onSearch={onSearch}
          filterOption={(input, option) =>
            (option!.children as unknown as string)
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(input.toLowerCase())
          }
        >
          <Option value="hellp">hello</Option>
        </Select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SchemeName;
```

Comment: Do you even need the `refetch` function and the `useEffect`? Couldn't you just use `useQuery` with `enabled: !!selectedAmc`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `useEffect`. `selectedAmc` is part of your `queryKey`, so when `selectedAmc` changes, react-query will create a new cache entry for that key and will start to fetch data unless the query is `disabled`.

Judging from the code, you'd want the query to be "lazy" - which means it's only disabled as long as there is no `selectedAmc`. There is a [section in the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries#lazy-queries) how to achieve this.

```
const { data: schemeData } = useQuery(
  ["post-scheme", { fund_house_name: selectedAmc }],
  postSchemeName,
  {
    enabled: !!selectedAmc,
  }
);
```